# How to display pagination with custom loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I've been scouring StackOverflow on and off all day looking for a solution to my problem. For some reason, I can't get pagination to work correctly with this loop. At first I was using "query_posts", which sort of worked.. although every page had the same posts. Here is my code...

```
<?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                    'cat' => '319',
                    'posts_per_page' => 8,
                    'paged' => $paged
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                    /* The Loop */
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                        $loop->the_post();
                        // do something
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a class="syncopate" href="';
                        the_permalink();
                        echo '">';
                        the_title();
                        echo '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                } ?>
                <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

It seems like this should work, but why doesn't it?

This is what function is called in the pagination.php...

```
function html5wp_pagination()
 {
  global $wp_query;
  $big = 999999999;
  echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
  ));
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried bumping the next/previous links directly before closing the if statement?

Comment: I did try that, but it was a no go...

Comment: If you have an error in your code, I don't see it. How many posts are found? Also, what exactly isn't working with the paging - not displaying, not writing the proper page, something else?

Comment: It's finding the number of posts I specify it to show, no matter what number I change it to. As for what wasn't working, the pagination links weren't being displayed.. only the posts. I found a solution that does work, however.

Answer (score 0):

So, this ended up working for me. Can anyone explain to me exactly why this worked and my original code did not?

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $temp = $wp_query;
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $wp_query -> query('cat=319&posts_per_page=10'.'&paged='.$paged);
                while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post">
                        <?php echo '<li>';
                            echo '<a class="syncopate" href="';
                        the_permalink();
                        echo '">';
                                the_title();
                                echo '</a>';
                            echo '</li>'; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                <div class="pagenav">
                    <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('Previous') ?></div>
                    <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('Next') ?></div>
                </div>

                <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```